# MySQL database design: use views to populate lookup table related keys

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have many tables with columns that contain keys to look up tables. For example the status of a booking can be "pending" or "paid" and these possible values are stored in a separate table.

```
product  |  status_id
----------------------
X        |  1
Y        |  2

id       |  value
----------------------
1        |  pending
2        |  paid
```

My question is if there are any drawbacks of using a (MySQL) view to populate these keys with strings as they are defined in the look up table, so that these don't need to be joined server-side anymore when the view is used instead? This view would thus look like this:

```
product  |  status
----------------------
X        |  pending
Y        |  paid
```

Thanks!

Comment: [The ENUM Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html)

Comment: `using a view to populate these keys with strings as they are defined in the look up table` sorry, I don't know what this means - but I see nothing wrong with your present configuration.

Comment: @Strawberry right now there are keys in the column "status_id". This would require a join on the server (back-end) to replace these with their string values: "pending" or "paid". This would result in a lot of tedious joins on the server and thus my question is if there are any drawbacks or things I should keep in mind if I use a view table to perform this join database-side.

Comment: `... don't need to be joined server-side anymore ...` There is nothing wrong with JOINs. What you want is actually denormalisation.

Comment: Generally, I would discourage the use of VIEWs in MySQL, because queries against views cannot take advantage of underlying indexes - rendering them (in my view) almost useless.